# how send props using Field redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I created a component and am using the Field of redux-form but I can't pass him the props, what should I do?

I'm trying to use the teste

componet

```
renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {  
    return (
      <View>
        <Item error={error && touched} rounded style={styles.inputGrp}>
          <Icon
            active
            name={input.name === "email" ? "mail" : "unlock"}
            style={{ color: "#fff" }}
          />
          <Input
            ref={c => (this.textInput = c)}
            placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={input.name === "email" ? "Email" : "Senha"}
            secureTextEntry={input.name === "password" ? true : false}   
            onChangeText={text => this.props.teste(text)}
            {...input}
          />
          {touched && error
            ? <Icon
              active
              style={styles.formErrorIcon}
              onPress={() => this.textInput._root.clear()}
              name="close"
            />
            : <Text />}
        </Item>
        {touched && error
          ? <Text style={styles.formErrorText1}>
            {error}
          </Text>
          : <Text style={styles.formErrorText2}>error here</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

my Field

```
<Field
    name="email"
    component={this.renderInput}
    type="email"
    validate={[email, required]}
    teste = {this.onChangeTextDestino}
/>
```

My Function

```
onChangeTextDestino (param) {
  try {
    this.setState({strEmail: param})
    Alert.alert(this.state.strEmail)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error", e)
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to pass the props for my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const RenderInput = this.renderInput;
<Field component={(props) => <RenderInput {...props} yourProps={yourProps} />} />
```

try something like this. (https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/#usage)

Comment: I have to do something besides?

Comment: It's normal this.props.yourProps is not gonna work. You need to extract it : renderInput({ yourProps, input, label ...})

Comment: This worked, thank you very much, you are a god, really helped me, I am truly grateful! :)

Comment: My dear, I noticed that imput loses focus every letter I type, what should I do?